# JS/ JQuery keyup and keydown Unpredictable behaviours on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am writing a web app where I collect the keystroke when the user type in the web forms. It is working fine so far on the desktop but on the mobile device and in particular Android devices it is not. The behaviours is kind unpredictable. For example:

- The backspace/delete key does not fire key event on some devices, but it does on some other devices.
- The modifier key (aka Shift key) does not fire key event on some device but it odes on other devices.
- The keycode is detected correctly on some devices and it does not on others.

For example on Samsung S4 using the native browser will always give keycode equal zero for any key. When I used the chrome browser version 45.0.2454.84 on Samsung S4 the key code was always 229 for most of the keys.

Using the native browser on Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, I get the correct key code for all the keys ( the same keycode I get using hardware keyboard on desktop) but the shift/modifier key does not fire

Using the Sony Xperia M4 Aqua, with chrome browser version 45.0.2454.84 I got the correct key code for all the keys. Agin the modifier key does not fire. When I use the native browser on the Sony Xperia I got the key code equal zero.

I can not really find a pattern even using the same browser "chrome browser version 45.0.2454.84"give different behaviors on the different devices.

On iPhone iPad and Windows Phone I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just flagged a bug in Chromium for that. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=531234

Comment: I think this is a good idea. However, for my app I need to come up with a different solution to figure the key code.

Comment: The Chromium guys say this is a Samsung keyboard bug and not a Chrome bug.

Comment: Actually it is not if I turn the text prediction on any android device I will get the same behaviours no matters it is a sony, nexus, HTC or Samsung keyboard.

Comment: @AbuUbaidah any update on this issue? I'm still seeing the same behavior